# multiprocessing.Manager.dict() TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object

Tags: python, multiprocessing

My code is as follows, I just want to use multiple processes to validate the shared data of the dictionary,but my code is reporting an error ,I have no idea why the error is reported, I hope you can help me

```
import multiprocessing
from prometheus_client import Gauge

def func(list_item, mydict):
    for item in list_item:
        mydict[item['metric_name']] =Gauge(
            name=item['metric_name'],
            documentation=item['description'],
            labelnames=item['label_config'],
        )

if __name__=="__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as MG:
        dict1 = dict({
            'metric_name': 'teset',
            'description': 'to_test',
            'label_config': 'namespace'
        })
        dict2 = dict({
            'metric_name': 'teset2',
            'description': 'to_test2',
            'label_config': 'namespace'
        })
        mydict = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
        mylist = multiprocessing.Manager().list()
        mylist.append(dict1)
        mylist.append(dict2)

        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(mylist,mydict))

        p.start()

        p.join()

    print(mydict)
```

The error reported as follow:

```
Process Process-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/project/teset.py", line 6, in func
    mydict[item['metric_name']] =Gauge(
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 834, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

Comment: You can not transfer this object to a different process using pickling/unpickling. Separate the data from the syncronization primitives.

Comment: Also, just searching for the error helps: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+cannot+pickle+%27_thread.lock%27+object. Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: As an aside: Why are you calling `manager.Manager()` repeatedly creating all these  manager processes? You only need one of these managers, `MG`, which you created with the `with` statement and then code, for example, `mydict = MG.dict()`. You will then need to move statement `print(mydict)` inside the `with` block.

Comment: Multiprocessing incurs overhead in creating processes and transferring data to and from different address spaces and using managed lists and dictionaries are also costly. Is creating these `Gauge` instances such an expensive CPU operation that justifies this? But even if the answer is yes, you are not using multiprocessing correctly since you are still trying to create all these `Gauge` instances in a *single* child process while the main process is doing nothing except waiting for the child process to complete.